# The SDK version is too high to submit to the App Store. What could I do?

Tags: xcode, swift, sdk, app-store

I want to submit an app to the App Store but when I go to send it for the test there is an error saying that the SDK is 9.1 and that's too high. What could I do the make the SDK 9.0 to submit the app?

The error message:

> Ungültiger SDK-Wert. Der für den SDK-Anteil von „LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS“ in „shootergame.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib“ angegebene Wert ist 9.1 und ist größer als der erlaubte Maximalwert von 9.0

Google translated version:

> Invalid SDK value. The SDK for the content of
>   "LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS" in "shootergame.app/Frameworks/
>   libswiftDarwin.dylib" specified value is 9.1 and is larger than the
>   allowable maximum value of 9.0

Comment: Use Xcode 7.0 to build and submit your app.  Xcode 7.1 is still in beta.

Comment: Set the Target Base SDK to 9.0 and the Deployment Target to 9.0 or lower.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot submit with a beta version of Xcode or the iOS SDK. Use Xcode 7.0 and you should be ok.

If you need something from iOS 9.1, you will have to wait for Apple to allow you to submit these to the App Store, which typically happens when the GM is released.